# Autofilm function / add many clips and transitions by one click. Which open source video editing software for linux suited?

Tags: transitions

I want to make a short movie from a holiday trip where I have taken many pictures and clips. I know the simple "autofilm"-feature of windows movie maker and it is quite useful. Because I switched to Kubuntu I am now looking for an open source video editing software which has compareable features:
- add many clips/pictures to time line
- create random transitions between all clips and pics
- create a Ken Burns effect (pan and zoom) for all pics

Of course these automatically added adjustments should remain editable. I tried Kdenlive, here I do not find a "add random transition for all clips/pics" feature. In OpenShot I can only add a manually adjusted Ken Burns effect but fo 300 pictures this would be too time consumptive ;)

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Has anyone an idea?

Comment: no ideas for an suitable open source video editor?